# Blank screen after moving WordPress to new server with same domain name

Tags: migration

I need to move my WP install. Domain name is the same. This is what I did:

1. I backed up the DB and "wp-content" folder.
2. I installed fresh WP install on new server
3. I emptied the DB of the fresh install and imported into it the
   content of the old DB (because prefix rules prevent me to create a DB carrying the same name as old DB)
4. I replaced the "wp-content" folder of new install by the
   "wp-content" of old install

Now I have the new DB (containing old content) with the new "wp-config.php" that comes with it. Yet I get a blank screen. Why?

Comment: I had that problem once, couldn't figure it out though. I took this route to fix it. It is obvious that you have your details of your db and a back-up as well. Delete your `wp-config.php`. Because wordpress can't find `wp-config.php` it will automatically take you to setting up a `wp-config.php`. When asked for db details, enter the details of your db. Wordpress will now create a new `wp-config.php` and you should be able to see your site normally. One thing I would advice is to flush your permalinks when you log in

Comment: Is there still a index.html in your root? that could couse the problem.

Comment: are you able to login into wp-admin? errors are enabled?

Comment: The WordPress SEO plugin was the culprit, not sure why/how. Renaming its folder through FTP to deactivate it solved  the issue.

Comment: I know it's obvious but no-one's mentioned logging; always worth checking what the HTTP response code for the blank page is, especially on new / unfamiliar servers, then tracing it back. Recently had an unhelpful 500 error in the Nginx access log, which [needed multiple changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677493/php-fpm-doesnt-write-to-error-log/23223585#23223585) to the php-fpm config, besides the usual WP_DEBUG constants, to actually write the errors somewhere.

Comment: @Maartje Thanks deleting index.html worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the active theme name is overridden .
Check the `'option_name' => 'current_theme'` value in `wp_options` . Is the `option_value` the same as your active theme name?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I was using a custom theme. When I moved things to a new server I started facing white screen but I was able to login to wp-admin. 
I updated my theme and activated again. It then started working.

See if that works for you. Just update / reinstall theme & activate again.